# How to filter by date=today in sqlite3 script

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, sqlite, export-to-csv

Here i have a piece of code which intention is to execute a query against a database (mainly in sqlite3 language) and after that, export the resulting table to an auto-named csv file.

```
set fch=%date:~11,4%%date:~8,2%%date:~5,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
sqlite3 -header -csv -cmd ".separator ','" C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db "select * from analysis;" > holaa%fch%.xlsx
```

My question is how to insert into the quoted query a filter to only show the data that matches the actual date (date is an actual field of the table that is exported)

Comment: What's the schema for your `analysis` table? What format are you using for dates?

Comment: the format set to the date field is something like "20/04/21 00:00:00". The schema of the table is composed by more than 10 fields that are irrelevant now.

Comment: "20/04/21 00:00:00"  Is this DMY or YMD?  Dates are not straightforward in SQLite.  There's dozens of ways to do them "wrong".  That's why we're asking for the schema and sample data.

Comment: here is the schema of the table analysis `CREATE INDEX analysis01 on analysis ( casereference );
CREATE INDEX analysis02 on analysis ( operator );
CREATE INDEX analysis03 on analysis ( subject );
CREATE INDEX analysis04 on analysis ( casereference );
CREATE INDEX analysis05 on analysis ( breed );` .Dates are DMY

Answer (score 0):

Use `strftime()`, one of the sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), to format the current date (`'now'`) in the same format as used in the database. Use that in a comparison in your query's WHERE clause.

I suggest converting all existing values to standard ISO-8601 formats instead of making up your own, though. It'll make things easier, both for interoperability with other software and so you can manipulate the dates with sqlite functions and other date/time builtins.

For example, if you used the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you could do

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE date_added = CURRENT_DATE
```

and avoid the `strftime()` completely.

Comment: Adding that piece of code to a batch dos file will work?A few moments ago i have put on test my script with that code and the results were that a csv fiel is created but without content.

Comment: @SantiagoCorso No... it's SQL, not batch, so it needs to go in the query. And there's no code in my answer you can actually just copy and paste and use with your data as is. You have to write up the right format argument for `strftime()` yourself. Your example was too vague for me to write one even if I wanted to. Doing so is a learning opportunity for you.